# Batch file to open multiple tabs in different time in firefox already opened

Tags: windows, firefox, batch, batch-file

I use portable firefox 60esr. until yesterday I could with a batch file to open in the same firefox open several tabs with a delay, but from today if I reopen firefox with batch file I appear a warning that firefox is already open and requires closure.

Before yesterday instead with a batch file I started several times firefox and in the same open firefox were opened new tabs what depends this warning that prevents me with a batch file to open new tabs with open firefox ?

[image]

This is batch file used

```
:: 'Firefox Tab 1'
START /B "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Firefox Portable ESR Quantum 1\FirefoxPortable.exe"
ping -n 10 localhost >nul 2>&1


:: 'Firefox Tab 1'
START /B "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Firefox Portable ESR Quantum 1\FirefoxPortable.exe"
ping -n 10 localhost >nul 2>&1

:: 'Firefox Tab 1'
START /B "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Firefox Portable ESR Quantum 1\FirefoxPortable.exe"
ping -n 10 localhost >nul 2>&1
```

This batch file opened firefox and then gradually opened 3 tabs with a delay by loading the default page of firefox.

Why does this batch file no longer work from today ?

I used this batch file to open firefox and after a gradually started I opened the new tabs.

Comment: Any particular reason why you need them to open with a specific delay, rather than all at once?

Comment: What version Windows? 32 or 64-bit? The most likely reason firefox did not close down properly was you had a firefox file open in another program.  It does not make any difference why firefox did not close down properly.  Put `taskkill /f /t /im firefoxportable.exe`before your first command to open firefox.

Comment: Hi, yes i need a delay to run macro after firefox full loaded, running firefox with a macro immediately sometimes can freeze firefox. I solved deleting firefox and reinstalled it, now works, i run firefox, after 1 minutes i run other tab to open without closing firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved deleting firefox and reinstalled it now works and i can execute the batch file added.